# i want to use list in args of celery beat

Tags: python

i have list and in list i have 10 city i want to use all of my city to the celery beat but i cant

```
cityList = ["Tehran", "Shiraz", "Mashhad", "Qom", "Isfahan", "Ardabil", "Hamedan", "Yazd", "Tabriz", "Zavareh"]

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'call_show_every_one_minute': {
        "task": 'ali111.get_weather',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': ([cityList], ),
    }
}
@app.task()
def get_weather(city):
    con = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port=6380, db=0, decode_responses=True)
    appid = "b3bf68fdfc6ba46923cd50cb8b9a79c3"
    URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    temp = con.get(city)
    if temp is not None:
        return temp
    try:
        PARAMS = {'q' :city, 'appid' :appid}
        r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
        city_temp = (r.json()['main']['temp']) - 273.15
        my_temp = f"{round(city_temp,1)}c"
        con.set(city, my_temp, ex=60)
        return my_temp
    except ConnectionError:
        return "not internet connection"
```

Comment: Why can't you change `get_weather` to take a list of cities instead of one city?

Comment: Just iterate over the list and call `get_weather` for each item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.